# como puedo retornar a una funcion en c++

Tags: c++, condiciones

Estoy realizando un programa con varias funciones, pero en una parte de mi programa quiero que al hacer una comprobación con un if al momento de ser verdadero quiero que me regrese de nuevo a una función donde solicito unos datos, dejo fragmento de código:

```
void solicitarDatos(int opcion) {
    int Dias=0;

    if(opcion == 1){
        cout<<"\nIngrese la cantidad de dias que desee rentar: ";
        cin>>Dias;
    } else if (opcion == 2){
        cout<<"\nIngrese la cantidad de dias que desee rentar: ";
        cin>>Dias;
    }else if (opcion == 3){
        cout<<"\nIngrese la cantidad de dias que desee rentar: ";
        cin>>Dias;
    }



    comprobarDatos(Dias);
    calcularTotal(Dias, opcion);

}
```

En la siguiente parte es donde realizo la comprobacion, si el dato ingresado es negativo quiero que me regrese a la funcion solicitarDatos

```
void comprobarDatos(int Dias){
    if (Dias < 1){
        cout<<"No se permiten numeros negativos";    
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Datos aceptados\n";
        int calcularTotal(int Dias, int opcion);
    }

}
```

Comment: ¿Qué quieres que sea verdadero y de dónde a dónde quieres ir? No entiendo la pregunta.

Comment: La función `comprobarDatos(Dias);` está llegando correcto? Creo que `calcularTotal(Dias, opcion);` estaría demás. Es un poco difícil entender tu pregunta si no explicas a detalle el error que ocurre en tu código y mucho menos si es sólo un fragmento.

Comment: Al momento de que se hace una comprobación , si el numero ingresado es negativo quiero que me regrese de nuevo a la función solicitarDatos hasta que ingrese un numero entero, porque en mi programa si pone un numero negativo se hace una multiplicación y al momento de hacer la multiplicación con el numero negativo muestra un dato que no deberia.

Comment: Pero de todas formas, así ocurra o no ocurra el if, estás ingresando a `calcularTotal(Dias, opcion);` y recibiendo como parámetro a `Dias` y `opcion`, por eso te comento que estaría demás esa función que está debajo de `comprobarDatos(Dias);`. Prueba lo siguiente: `else { cout<<"Datos aceptados\n"; calcularTotal(Dias, opcion); }`

Answer (score 0):

Un programa en ejecución tiene a su disposición, simplificando, dos regiones de memoria:

- montón o *heap*
- pila o *stack*

El *heap* se refiere a la memoria dinámica, la RAM del equipo. De esta memoria se puede pedir toda la que el sistema sea capaz de ofrecer.

El *stack* es una región especial de memoria gestionada por el propio programa. La cantidad de memoria de esta región está muy limitada y, si se llena, el programa dejará de funcionar. Esta región sirve para varios propósitos:

- Se almacenan las variables locales de las funciones
- Se usa para tener constancia de los retornos desde las funciones

Vamos a centrarnos en el segundo uso. Cada vez que se llama a una función, el programa apunta en la pila la dirección de memoria de la instrucción a la que debe saltar el programa cuando abandone la nueva función y seguidamente se invoca la función.

Cuando el programa alcanza el final de la función acudirá a la pila para recuperar la dirección de memoria guardada previamente y saltará a dicha dirección para continuar con la ejecución.

Es decir, una función ni sabe ni tiene que saber desde dónde la están invocando. Una función únicamente debe preocuparse de hacer su trabajo. Cuando lo termine ya habrá otros que se encargarán de saber qué es lo siguiente que hay que ejecutar.

Dicho esto, para abandonar una función simplemente usa `return`:

```
void comprobarDatos(int Dias){
    if (Dias < 1){
        cout<<"No se permiten numeros negativos";
        return;  
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Datos aceptados\n";
    }
}
```

Sin embargo, yo creo que lo que tu estás pretendiendo se parece más a esto:

```
bool comprobarDatos(int dias)
{
    if (dias< 1)
    {
        cout << "No se permiten numeros negativos\n";
        return false;
    }

    cout << "Datos aceptados\n";
    return true;
}

int solicitarDatos(int opcion)
{
    int dias=0;

    if(opcion == 1){
        cout<<"\nIngrese la cantidad de dias que desee rentar: ";
        cin>>Dias;
    } else if (opcion == 2){
        cout<<"\nIngrese la cantidad de dias que desee rentar: ";
        cin>>Dias;
    }else if (opcion == 3){
        cout<<"\nIngrese la cantidad de dias que desee rentar: ";
        cin>>Dias;
    }

    return dias;
}

int main()
{
    int opcion = /* ... */

    int dias;
    do
    {
        dias = solicitarDatos(opcion);
    } while (!comprobarDatos(dias);

    calcularTotal(dias, opcion);
}
```

Ahora el programa te estará pidiendo los datos eternamente mientras no introduzcas datos válidos

Comment: Quizá sea excesivo mencionar lo del stack y el heap. Me parece más interesante que en C++ se puede ir a un lugar arbitrario cómo lo desea en el código por medio de `goto` aunque hay que tener mucho cuidado. Además que se puede hacer más fácil como lo planteas al final.

Comment: @Mateo no uses `goto` jamás de los jamases. Generas código spaguetti y puedes acabar con variables no inicializadas si no tienes muuuucho cuidado. Salvo en partes muy muy concretas y críticas de ciertos sistemas, como el núcleo de linux. Fuera de esos contextos, `goto` debería estar prohibido

Comment: He estado más de 10 años programando en C y C++ y **nunca** he tenido que usar `goto`

Comment: @Mateo la idea de explicar lo de la pila era para que el OP entendiese por qué el `return` es una posible solución. Dejar la solución sin más o mal explicada me parecía contraproducente

Comment: Tampoco nos vayamos al otro extremo. Es importante saber que cuando una función finaliza su ejecución, la función original retoma el control. Además si `solicitarDatos` llama a `comprobarDatos` y esta a su vez llama a `solicitarDatos`, hay una especie de recursión no deseada. Sobre el `goto`, la mayoría de las veces hay una mejor manera de hacer las cosas y cuando no, toca.

Comment: @Mateo por supuesto, en este caso es absurdo que `comprobarDatos` llame a `solicitarDatos`. Es producto de un mal diseño. Sin embargo con respecto al goto, pienso exactamente lo mismo. Salvo en el caso de sistemas muy específicos, siempre habrá un diseño que no implique usar `goto`.